# Retrieve child entry from Firebase Realtime Database without []. - Swift 5

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a little stuck with something small but that is giving me some headaches! I have a Realtime Database and I am able to retrieve the information I need from it. My only problem is that instead of printing for example (ex.: 200) is printing (ex.: [200])!

This is my code:

```
func readData() {

  FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference().child("Available_Funds").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                return
            }
            let amountWallet = value.values
            print(amountWallet)
            self.currentBalanceLabel.text = "$" + "\(amountWallet)"
            print("\(value)")
        })
    }
```

Right now what I get printed with this code is $[200] for example, instead of just $200, which is what I intend to get.

Tried looking online, but no luck with this! Does someone know how to remove these square brackets from printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values` is an `Array` -- thus the `[]`. When you say `value.values`, you're asking for all of the values of the key/value pairs in `snapshot.value`.

If you intend to get a *single* value from it, you would use `amountWallet[0]` to get the first element. Keep in mind that this will crash if `amountWallet` has 0 elements (arrays are zero indexed).

`amountWallet.first` will give you an Optional that will be safe to use, but you would need to unwrap it for printing:

```
let amountWallet = value.values
if let singleAmount = amountWallet.first {
  print(singleAmount)
  self.currentBalanceLabel.text = "$" + "\(singleAmount)"
}
```

Comment: This have worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked. After 15 minutes from the initial question, you can use the green checkmark to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Done! Once again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling it back as an array of strings `[String: Any]`

You can either change this (remove []) or access the first element in the array: `amountWallet[0]`.

Comment: Thank you so much!